# why is my jade script tag inside the body tag?

Tags: pug

This is my jade layout file:

```
doctype html
html
    head
      title= title
      link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    body
       block content
    script(src='/javascripts/stafflist.js')
```

And this is my extend file:

```
extends layout
block content
   div(id='itemlist')
     p item List
     form(id='staffnewup',method='post',action='/newup')
       button(type='submit') Add
```

But why does my Opera gives me this?:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="itemlist">
<p>item List</p>
<form id="staffnewup" method="post" action="/newup">
<button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
</div>
<script src="/javascripts/stafflist.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Should't my script tag be outside the body?
I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every tag must be placed inside either `<head>` or `<body>`. Any tag placed outside them will not work.

You've made a mistake by placing your script at the wrong place and Jade is correcting that mistake by giving you the valid output.